# uiimageview.image appears to be warped on iOS 8 simulator

Tags: uiimageview, ios8, uiimage, simulator

The problem is I no longer have any access to any devices that run iOS 8, so I can't confirm whether this only happens in the simulator.

[image: on iOS 8 simulator] [image: what it supposed to look like]

Nothing special with the code. just `imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon")` and the contentMode is set to `.center` and I just dropped the icons into .xcassets. The icons are exported from Sketch.

Comment: Try to set contentMode to AspectFit.

Comment: Nope, still warped.

Comment: do you have demo of this if yes please share the link so that i will check it

Comment: just start a new project, set deployment target to 8.0. drop an image view into the storyboard. set image. run on any simulator 8.1.

Comment: does it behave same on device and simulator? I have same problem, but only in simulator.